# How to bind to sibling element in DataTemplate?

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate

I have the following TreeView:

```xml
<TreeView Grid.Column="2" x:Name="itemTreeView" Margin="0" SelectedItemChanged="SelectionChanged">
  <TreeView.Resources>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MarketGroup}">
      <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemsSource>
        <Binding Path="children"/>
      </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemsSource>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding marketGroupName}" ToolTip="{Binding description}"/>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ItemType}">
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Source="{Binding itemImage}" Height="{Binding Sibling.ActualHeight}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding typeName}"  ToolTip="{Binding description}"/>
      </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

So what I want to do is have the Image located in the DataTemplate Bind it's height to the Actual height of the TextBlock beside it so they are the same size. So far all I have been able to find with reguards to referencing a sibling relies on having x:Name defined and refering to it by name, but it is my understanding I can't name an element in a DataTemplate as it is only a template. Alternativly if there was a way to bind the parent StackPanel to the TextBlock then bind the Image size to the parent should work too if that is possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`x:Name` on the TextBlock, `ElementName` in the Binding.

```
<Image 
    Source="{Binding itemImage}" 
    Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=SiblingTextBlock}"
    />
<TextBlock 
    x:Name="SiblingTextBlock" 
    Text="{Binding typeName}"  
    ToolTip="{Binding description}"
    />
```

Who told you that won't work in a `DataTemplate`? You naturally won't be able to reference that name from *outside* the template, because there could be zero or more than instances of the template instantiated. But within the template it's fine.

Comment: Perhaps they were referring to referencing it from outside the `DataTemplate` I tested it out and it is doing what I was looking for. Guess I should have just tried it anyway.

Comment: @themightymanuel I think that must've been it. A lot of people run into the scoping thing.